# Some file lost in MySQL database. How to re-create it in proper way?

Tags: mysql

The problem is, that one MYI and one MYD file from MySQL database has been accidentally deleted. The only file left intact is FRM one. Only one table from the whole database is damaged that way, all other tables are OK and the database works generally fine, except the table with deleted files, which is obviously inaccessible.

There's a full database dump in pure SQL format available.

The question is, how do I re-create these files and table in safe and proper manner?

My first idea was to extract the full `create table` command from the dump and run it on live database. It's not so easy, as the whole dump file has over 10GB, so any operations within its content are really pain in . Yes, I know about `sed` and know how to use it - but I consider it the last option to choose.

Second and current idea is to create copy of this database on independent server, make a dump of the table in question and then use resulting SQL file to create the table again on the production server. I'm not quite experienced with MySQL administration tasks (well, just basic ones), but **for me** this option seems to be safe and reasonable.

1. Will the second option work as I expect?
2. Is it the best option, or are there any more recommendable solutions?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Yes, the second option will work, and seems like your best option to me.

Comment: It worked like a charm. Quick, easy and elegant. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to copy the table you deleted. There's a chance mysqld still has an open file handle to the data files you deleted. On UNIX/Linux/OS X, a file isn't truly deleted while some process still has an open file handle to it.

So you *might* be able to do this:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE mytable_copy LIKE mytable;
mysql> INSERT INTO mytable_copy SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

If you've restarted MySQL Server since you deleted the files, this won't work. If the server has closed its file handle to the data file, this won't work. If you're on Windows, I have no idea.

The next simplest solution is to restore your existing 10GB dump file to a temporary instance of MySQL Server, as you said. I'd use [MySQL Sandbox](https://mysqlsandbox.net) but some people would use a virtual machine, or if you're using an AWS environment, launch a spot EC2 instance or a small RDS instance.

Then dump just the table you need:

```
mysqldump -h tempserver mydatabase mytable > mytable.sql
```

Then restore it to your real server.

```
mysql -h realserver mydatabase < mytable.sql
```

(I'm omitting the user & password options, I prefer to put those in `.my.cnf` anyway)

Comment: The first option unfortunately didn't work, despite MySQL server wasn't stopped. OpenBSD if it matters anything.
But the second solution worked like a charm. Quick, easy and elegant. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Yeah, it was just a chance. MySQL may close file handles on its own from time to time.